# What does "...." mean?

Tags: windows-10

I wrote some codes to create a directory named "E:\hkhkhkhk\...." in c++. It actually created "...." iteratively. And the parent directory "hkhkhkhk" cannot be removed.

I was wondering how the system explains "....".

The code is as below, execute it in virtual machine.

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    if (!CreateDirectoryA("E:\\hkhkhkhk\\....\\", NULL))
        cout << GetLastError() << endl;

    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

Josh

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Windows doesn't allow programs to use paths ending with a dot; whenever a program tries to access such a path, all dots are quietly removed from the end.

You bypassed this restriction when creating the directory since your path actually ends with a backslash, but other programs (e.g. Windows Explorer) don't do this.

So when you double-click the directory in Explorer, it tries to change to `E:\hkhkhkhk\....` but actually gets `E:\hkhkhkhk\` (which is the same as the parent directory), creating the *illusion* of infinite recursion when in reality you never go anywhere at all.

Comment: Your explanation is very helpful, thx alot!